# How to represent semantics with Combinatory Logic

Tags: semantics

How is Combinatory Logic relevant to software design?  For example, can one transform programs into CL?  If so, how?  Does CL provide a canonical representation for programs?

Comment: Combinatory logic is Turing-complete, just like many other programming formalisms. Are two-counter programs relevant to software design?

Comment: Combinatory logic is relevant to lower levels of representation of programs in compilers. It turns out that combinators, in the absence of variable bindings, are significantly closer to a straightforward implementation in machine language. See e.g. [this](http://www.diku.dk/OLD/undervisning/2003f/213/Gmachine.pdf)